# Is cisitive relation defined just as transitive relation is defined?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

A relation $R$ on a set $X$ is transitive if, for all elements $a, b, c \in X$, whenever $aRb$ and $bRc$, then $aRc$ (from [wiki](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation), modified). "Trans" [means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/trans-#English) on the other or opposite side. $b$ in $aR\color{red}b$ and $\color{red}{b}Rc$ is on opposite sides.

"Cis" [means](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cis#English) on the same side. I am wondering why there is no talk of a relation, which I think, I am justified to call cisitive relation, whose definition *should be* "a relation $R$ on a set $X$ such that, for all elements $a, b, c \in X$, whenever $aRb$ and $cRb$, then $aRc$  and $cRa.$

Comment: I think your etymological argument is specious. Still, it is interesting to think about why transitive relationships work the way they do. Certainly there is no difference in the symmetric setting. Perhaps the usual definition is more "natural" because we like to think of $aRb$ as a relationship going "from" $a$ "to" $b$, in which case this is simple composition? Just a thought.

Comment: I guess it's possible to have a relationship such that if we have $aRb$ and $cRb$ then $aRc$ and $cRa$ since there are infinitely many relations. But there's no definition of a "cisitive relation," as far as I know, and maybe it's because it's not significant enough to talk about. (Also, "cisitive" isn't a word, after a quick Google search.)

Comment: @Accelerator I created this word.

Comment: If you ca come up with some interesting consequences it would be good.   For instance,  equivalence relations have nice properties,  and are characterized by being reflexive,  symmetric and transitive.

Comment: Can you think of any interesting examples, Osmium, of "cisitive" relations that aren't transitive?

Comment: @GerryMyerson All the examples of cisitive relations I can think of are transitive as well!

Comment: Well, maybe that's why there is no talk of it.

Comment: Your definition of a "cisitive relation" is just the definition of a [left Euclidean relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_relation). Actually, they should be called "left cisitive"; right Euclidean relations would then be "right cisitive".

Answer (score 3):

This is a nice puzzle about directed graphs (the (directed) graph of a binary relation $R$ on $X$ has the set $X$ as the vertices, and a directed edge from $a$ to $b$ iff $aRb$.)

Renaming for convenience, the cisitivity axiom asserts that if $aRc$ and $bRc$, then $aRb$ and $bRa$: the presence of certain edges implies the presence of certain other ones. So you can start with any relation (or digraph) and repeatedly add the implied edges until the result is cisitive: this is the *cisitive closure* $R^{cis}$ of $R$ (or $G$).

It’s useful to start with some simple examples. If $R$ is cisitive, and $aRc$ for some $c\ne a$, then taking $b=a$ in the axiom, we conclude $aRa$. That is, in the graph, if $a$ has outdegree at least 1 then there’s a loop at $a$. (So, if we’re constructing the cisitive closure, we get to add in a loop unless $a$ is a *sink* (i.e. has outdegree 0.))

Now suppose $aRb$ and $bRb$: the axiom tells us that both $aRb$ and $bRa$. We had assumed the former, but the latter is new - $R$ is in fact both reflexive and symmetric on the set $\{a,b\}$.

These two observations tell us that cisitization tends to introduce loops and thereby symmetrizes edges. Some examples to check for yourself:

1. The cisitive closure of a cycle graph is the complete graph on those vertices (with loops).
2. The cisitive closure of a directed path with $n$ vertices is the complete graph on the first $n-1$ vertices, together with the original edge into the $n$th vertex.
3. The cisitive closure of a $W$ graph (three vertices on top, two vertices on the bottom, and four edges pointing down, as in a W) adds **all** edges among the top vertices, including the self-loops.
4. When computing the cisitive closure, sinks remain sinks, and no additional edges are ever added going into them.

In general (exercise) you get the cisitive closure $R^{cis}$ of $R$ as follows: let $\sim$ be the equivalence relation generated by $R$ (its reflexive, symmetric, transitive closure). Then $aR^{cis}b$ iff either $aRb$, or if $a\sim b$ and neither $a$ nor $b$ was a sink in $R$.

As @AndreasBlass points out, a reflexive relation has no sinks (in our sense here), so the reflexive cisitive relations are precisely the equivalence relations.

So cisitivity and transitivity are much more similar than we might have expected.

Comment: Implicit in this answer but  perhaps worth stating separately: Equivalence relations are exactly the reflexive cisitive relations.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Yes - very nice observation.